How to Handle Timezones and Ensure Date Consistency in a Multi-Timezone Application?
In our application, we manage data from multiple timezones, and we need to ensure that date consistency is maintained across the entire system. I have a few questions regarding best practices for handling timezones and dates:
Should we convert all dates to UTC before processing the requests? If so, what are the best practices and common pitfalls to avoid during this conversion process?
If converting to UTC is not the recommended approach, what is the current best practice for handling dates and times in a multi-timezone environment?
How can we ensure that the dates displayed to users in different timezones are accurate and consistent with their local time?
